# View my API request URL (from the API's perspective) using a Linux Command Line Utility?

Tags: json, google-maps, curl

I want to see what my request URL is that I'm making to a JSON API. I suspect my URL parameters are being stripped by a proxy, but I can't confirm.  Is there a way to see what my request URI is using cURL or WGET, or any other Linux CLI utility?  How???

Here is my example request:

```
curl -v https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=783++Faxon+%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94112&client=gme-user2345&signature=jfkdEdsn7bdXCBfaReAPc3FSSMo=
```

Comment: The request URL is `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=783++Faxon+%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94112&client=gme-user2345&signature=jfkdEdsn7bdXCBfaReAPc3FSSMo=`  What are you trying to do? That works for me (if I remove the client/signature info).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use:

```
curl -ivs https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=783++Faxon+%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94112&client=gme-user2345&signature=jfkdEdsn7bdXCBfaReAPc3FSSMo=
```

> GET /maps/api/geocode/json?address=783++Faxon+%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94112 HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-v` option with cURL DOES output the GET request URL.

However, I was not wrapping the request URL in quotations, and for some reason this was resulting in the `client` and `signature` parameters being stripped from the request URL.

Wrapping the request URL in quotes within my cURL command has resolved the issue, and now the output from the `curl -v` command shows the full request URL.

```
curl -v 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=783++Faxon+%2C+San+Francisco%2C+CA+94112&client=gme-user2345&signature=jfkdEdsn7bdXCBfaReAPc3FSSMo='
```